# Syntax to see route planning between two points?

Tags: google-search, google-maps

In most cases, to find out a distance or expected travel time between two points, I use Google Maps (using Chrome, desktop PC). To do so, the typical steps are:

- Type a location (say 'Munich') into the URL-bar in Chrome (which triggers the Google search)
- On the result page, click on "Maps". This opens the map showing Munich
- Click on "route planner". Munich becomes the destination.
- Type the second location, say "Paris"
- If you need to navigate from Munich to Paris, switch the two locations

Five steps for one route - I wonder if there is a shorter way to achieve the same result:

Is there a syntax to make Google show the route planner right from the search query?

<sub>My idea is something like `Munich -> Paris` (which is, obviously, not a solution).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

If you're already at [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com), typing `{starting point} to {destination}` is all you need to do. So, for example:

```
munich, germany to paris, france
```

If you're trying to do it from the generic Google Search (perhaps from the Chrome Omnibar) the same syntax does it:

```
munich, germany to paris, france
```

It'll often give you a number of different options (like ads to buy rail tickets) but should also give you a small map from Google Maps with the distance, time, and basic route.

Personally, since I know I'm looking for directions, I'll just head to Maps first. Then I get exactly what I want without extra clutter.

The key seems to be the **to** between the two places. `from` ***to*** `destination`.

For what it's worth, that syntax also works at [Bing](http://www.bing.com).